# Understanding Logistic Regression Cost function

Tags: logistic-regression, linear-regression, optimization, cost-function

Linear Regression cost function:

$$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_{\theta}(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2$$

where:

$$h_{\theta}(x) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1$$

Logistic Regression cost function

$$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m - (y^{(i)} \times log(h_{\theta}(x{(i)})) + (1-y{(i)}) \times log(1 - h_{\theta}(x{(i)})))$$

where:

$$h_{\theta}(x) = g(\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2)$$

Intuitively `linear regression` is easy to understand as it optimizes the average squared distance between hypothesis and training data. But in case of `logistic regression`, I failed to understand the cost function.

What does the logistic regression cost function represent?

Comment: It's negative log likelihood, so if you minimize this function, you consequently maximize likelihood of the data. They derive it for the case with 2 classes [here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/logistic-regression-note.pdf).

Comment: Likelihood function in this case is $\prod h_\theta (x^{(i)})^{y^{(i)}} (1 - h_\theta (x^{(i)})^{(1-y^{(i)})}$. Negative log likelihood is equal to your cost function (except for the multiplier).

Comment: Atinesh: In this formulation $y^{(i)} \in \{0,1\}$, so either way one of the terms gets eliminated. It's a succint way of expression of defining this piecewise function. When you take the logarithm the products separate into sums.

Comment: I acknowledge it is not that compliant to post a link as an answer, but for the case in point the following video by Andrew Ng which can really help original poster https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIQlmHxI6-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way my intuition works for logistic regression is simple, say you are trying to classify if you have a picture with a dog on it, if that is the case, you output 1 (true), if not, you output 0 (false)

The cost function essentially represents the diff between what your model output (imagine, you have a dog in a picture, and your model outputs 0.75 instead of 1, your cost is 0.25).

Now, this is not a very mathematical way to put it, but at least it has helped me a lot to understand logistic regression.